# Networkx get ancestors with depth

Tags: python, networkx

Is there anything within NetworkX that will combine the functionality of ancestors and provide the depth of each object?

I want to get a dictionary of all [ancestors in NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html), and get the depth from the source for each of those. Right now the function returns a set, but I'd like to know how deep each item is in the dependencies of an object.

My source is a sql table that has the input and output of a pipeline, which I then turn into a directed graph. Example:

```
input   output
b       a
c       a
x       b
y       b
z       b
w       b
l       c
m       c
```

and after running ancestors I have the set of everything that is in the chain, but I need a way to also be able to say that x is a level 3 or depth 3 object.

I've been looking through the various functions like [traversal](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html), but nothing jumps out at me as providing this functionality. Do I need to create my own loop to recreate ancestors with depth at this point?

Comment: Finding the depth of each node in a tree is a long-established algorithm.  I provided a link to a prior question which shows the basic recursion; you merely need to assign the computed depth to each node as you finish it's children.  This is really something you look up in basic graph algorithms.

Comment: This was a question about NetworkX, not just how to search for depth. Can this be re-opened as the linked question is not what I was asking about?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you've done the preprocessing, and have a graph `pipe`, and you know the root node `a`.

```
single_source_shortest_path_length(path, a)
```

This returns a dict of nodes and path lengths.  The depth is that path length plus 1.